# ANDROID INTENTION FATAL ERROR!!! java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

This is my first question at stackoverflow, so please help me if I'm doing anything wrong/improper.

I trying to create a basic practice app to call an activity (activity2) from activity1 using implicit intention. But for some reason I have this error driving me nuts:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick.
```

Here is the code for activity1:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
private final String CLASS_NAME = "FirstActiviy";
private int request_Code = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity);
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onCreate invoked!" );
}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onStart invoked!" );
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onPause invoked!!" );
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onResume invoked!!" );
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onStop invoked!!!" );
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onDestroy INVOKED!!!" );
}

public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onRestart invoked!!" );
}


// event handler for the button (activity 2)
public void onClick(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent("com.seneca.lab2b.abbas"));

}

// event handler for a button (activity 3)
public void onClick3(View view) {

    startActivity( new Intent( this, ThirdActivity.class ) );

}
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
09-15 01:45:42.070 10359-10359/com.seneca.lab2b E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.seneca.lab2b, PID: 10359
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.seneca.lab2b.abbas }
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1798)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                                      at com.seneca.lab2b.FirstActivity.onClick(FirstActivity.java:59)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And the layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/display"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/display3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="onClick3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is c++? Looks a lot like Java ;-) Could you post the layout xml for FirstActivity?

Comment: post your `firstactivity` layout

Comment: OMG, i am sooo sorry, this is indeed java, i am working on c++ projects and java projects simultaneously so was a bit confused. And sure i will also post the xml right now.

Comment: the xml file you posted is the manifest file, please post the layout file

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: Does your other button work? And why do you use the Intent like you do for the first button instead of creating it just like the other one?

Comment: Just change the name of onClick in your layout and change the method name accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for that, but as i stated in my initial question i want something like this: "The event handler should use an implicit intent to invoke the SecondActivity class from FirstActivity. The action name used 
    by the intent filter should be “com.seneca.lab2b..
"

Answer (score 0):

In some device xml onclick method not working because new version of android it's not support onclick(view).
So remove in xml and create onclick in JAVA class.

Comment: Can you help me as to how should i do that, would really appreciate it if you could help.Btw, onClick works for the Activity3 button (explicit intention)

Comment: First remove android:onClick="onClick" this line from xml code

Comment: then give findviewbyid of your Button and then do setonclick method for this button in onCreate.

Comment: As i said Mr Hardik, i am new to programming in android, so could you help with more specifics? like the code line?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/display"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/display3"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Java class:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
private final String CLASS_NAME = "FirstActiviy";
private int request_Code = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity);
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onCreate invoked!" );
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             startActivity(newIntent(FirstActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class));
            }
        });

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             startActivity(newIntent(FirstActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class));
            }
        });
}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onStart invoked!" );
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onPause invoked!!" );
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onResume invoked!!" );
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onStop invoked!!!" );
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onDestroy INVOKED!!!" );
}

public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d( CLASS_NAME, "onRestart invoked!!" );
}
}
```